# VPN Connection from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vpn

so the issue is basically that any attempt to connect to my office VPN fails in Ubuntu 14.04.

There are no special settings but worth mentioning it's to PPTP.

I can ping the server easily enough. I'm not sure what kind of information I can put out here to make this more diagnosable but please let me know.

The output is as follows:

```
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 18760
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: init (1)
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home pppd[18764]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <info> VPN connection 'Test2' (Connect) reply received.
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home pppd[18764]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home pppd[18764]: Using interface ppp0
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home pppd[18764]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/26
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home pptp[18767]: nm-pptp-service-18760 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Sep 29 17:24:27 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Sep 29 17:24:28 pedri-home pptp[18780]: nm-pptp-service-18760 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Sep 29 17:24:29 pedri-home pptp[18780]: nm-pptp-service-18760 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Sep 29 17:24:29 pedri-home pptp[18780]: nm-pptp-service-18760 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Sep 29 17:24:29 pedri-home pptp[18780]: nm-pptp-service-18760 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Sep 29 17:24:29 pedri-home pptp[18780]: nm-pptp-service-18760 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Sep 29 17:24:29 pedri-home pptp[18780]: nm-pptp-service-18760 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 150).
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home pppd[18764]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home pppd[18764]: Connection terminated.
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home pppd[18764]: Modem hangup
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home pptp[18767]: nm-pptp-service-18760 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home pptp[18767]: nm-pptp-service-18760 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home pppd[18764]: Exit.
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: message repeated 2 times: [ <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1]
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home pptp[18780]: nm-pptp-service-18760 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home pptp[18780]: nm-pptp-service-18760 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home pptp[18780]: nm-pptp-service-18760 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Sep 29 17:24:58 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Sep 29 17:25:03 pedri-home NetworkManager[912]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems trying to set up a VPN over my home ADSL connection.
One thing I had some success with was changing the MTU on the PPPoE connection to Manual, and setting it at 1432.
It still drops randomly from time to time, but holds up long enough to do some work...